# Force item to always be in last position using Packery

Tags: jquery, css, packery

I want to force a grid item to always be in the last position even after moving items around.

I am thinking a good approach would be to

```
//get the total number of items
var totalItems = $('.grid-item').length; 

//adjust the .last item to be the last item in the array ????
$('.last') grid order is totalItems + 1 

//layout items again
$grid.packery('layout');
```

..and execute that after a change is made.

I have created a fiddle which is complete except for the magic to make the order update:
https://jsfiddle.net/2buqd4nu/

I would be happy to accept any other approach that would achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The built in "append" method does, quote:

> Adds and lays out newly appended item elements to the end of the
>   layout.

More info: https://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended

If you want even more power over the array and are not afraid of chopping up the Packery file, you can call up the `elems` array. See: https://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html#getitemelements.

Hoping this helps!